# Can't insert into pivot table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I have a pivot table in my database that combines users and loans. The table is the following.

```
user_id
loan_id
amount
```

Now I have the following code to insert data into the database

```
    $user = User::find(2);
    $user->loans()->create([
        // Some database insertion
    ]);

    $user->loans()->attach(2, ['amount' => '500']);
```

And I am getting this error...

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'amount' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `loan_user` (`loan_id`, `user_id`) values (42, 2)) in file G:\Development\final-project\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php
```

My loans and users have a many-to-many relationship and I also have the pivot table named loan_user.
What am I doing wrong here?

#### Edit

Here's the migration of my pivot table

```
    Schema::create('loan_user', static function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('loan_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->integer('amount');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

#### Something Important

I made that amount column nullable. Then it was not throwing any error but sometimes the amount is 500 and sometimes it's null. I have no idea what's going on.

#### Solution

I solved this by creating the loan first and then attaching it to the user and pivot amount. Something like this.

```
    $loan = Loan::create([
        // something
    ]);

    $user->loan()->attach(['amount' => 500]);
```

Comment: My first question why do you use column `amount` in pivot table?

Comment: multiple users can have multiple amounts in multiple loans. Let's say, five users are involved in a loan with a specified amount, the user can be a lender or borrower but that user might also be involved in other loans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to create a record via a many-to-many relationship which is why it is failing. Instead, you can create the loan separately and attach with something like this:

```php
$loan = Loan::create([
    // data
]);

$user->loans()->attach(
    $loan, [
        'amount' => 500,
    ]
);
```

Also, your `loans` relationship should look something like this:

```php
public function loans(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Loan::class)
        ->withPivot('amount')
        ->withTimestamps();
}
```

This will add the amount to pivot data when querying.

Refs: https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#attaching-detaching

Comment: But, I already did that, It didn't work. My code didn't reach to the line where I am attaching. It fails in the $loan->create line.

Comment: Oops, sorry, you were right. I have to insert the loan first and then attach it to the user with the pivot amount. Thanks....

Comment: Yeah, sorry if I didn't make it clear earlier. I've updated my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

You have to use like this

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Loan', 'amount')->withPivot('amount');
```

and If you insert multiple rows at a time then you have to use like this

```
$user->loans()->attach('2',['amount'=>500]);
```

[For More details](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/inserting-data-in-pivot-table)

Comment: The problem here is that my code doesn't reach the line where I am attaching, It fails when creating the loan

Comment: Have any column `amount` in your pivot table??