# Laravel Eloquent Model can't sync with pivot data in Many-to-Many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I would like to sync the data instead of attach the data to the particular relationship.

Pivot relation UserModel code

```
public function carts(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class,'user_carts')->withPivot('quantity');
    }
```

The attach code is

```
User::find(1)->carts()->attach($s,["quantity"=>1]);
```

The sync code is

```
User::find(1)->carts()->sync($s,["quantity"=>1]);
```

When I try to compile the sync, those pivot relation that matched user_id = 1 does not have the "1" in its respective quantity column.

If I would like to achieve the sync function without using attach, how can I do it because the attach() will create multiple redundant data in my database.

Comment: I see there is two table `user` and `cart` but how come `product` model. For more details pls https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66811609/cant-insert-into-pivot-table/66812016#66812016

Comment: The pivot table cart is to connect product and user model together.

Comment: What is the relation `users` and `carts` in your code?

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass key values in the `sync` method.
Assuming `$s` is the id (key) to be synced:

```
User::find(1)->carts()->sync([$s => ["quantity"=>1]]);
```

Comment: ErrorException
Illegal offset type
http://localhost:8000/api/pivot

Comment: I can't help you with just that information.

Comment: actually my $s = Product::whereIn("id",[4,10])->get();

Comment: your solution will work when the $s only return a single id but in my scenario, there will be multiple id will be passed through on the $s.

Comment: So map over `$s` and add `['quantity' => 1]` on every record.

Comment: $s = $s->map(function($value){
        return [
            $value->id => ["quantity"=>1]
        ];
    });

Comment: ErrorException
Array to string conversion

Comment: Modified code: User::find(1)->carts()->sync($s);

Comment: The array structure that it will produce is incorrect, try dumping `$s` after the map.