# syntax error, unexpected '-=' (T_MINUS_EQUAL), expecting ']'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have written this at the Controller for updating `balance` field which exists at the `user_wallet` table (which is the pivot table in `User` & `Wallet` Models - many to many relationship).

```
$wallet = Wallet::find($wallet_id);
if($value_added_type == '-')
   $wallet->users()->updateExistingPivot($user_id,["balance"-=$amount_add_value]);
else
   $wallet->users()->updateExistingPivot($user_id,["balance"+=$amount_add_value]);
```

So I said `"balance"-=$amount_add_value` because I needed to calculate balance in this way:

`balance = balance - $amount_added_value`

And if `$value_added_type` is increasing:

`balance = balance + $amount_added_value`

But now I get this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '-=' (T_MINUS_EQUAL), expecting ']'
```

So how to calculate `balance` properly in this case ?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Thanks in advance.

> **UPDATE #1:**

I tried this for updating `balance` field:

```php
// Getting balance field in pivot table based on user_id & wallet_id
$bal = Wallet::with("users")->whereHas('users', function ($query) use ($wallet_id,$user_id) {
    $query->where('wallet_id',$wallet_id);
    $query->where('user_id',$user_id);
});

// updating balance field    
$wallet = Wallet::find($wallet_id);
if($value_added_type == '-'){
    $wallet->users()->updateExistingPivot($user_id,["balance" => ($bal - $amount_add_value)]);
}else{
    $wallet->users()->updateExistingPivot($user_id,["balance" => ($bal + $amount_add_value)]);
}
```

But now I get this error:

> Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to number

Comment: Follow this instruction https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66811609/cant-insert-into-pivot-table/66812016#66812016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`["xxx" -= 123]` or `["xxx" += 123]` is not a valid PHP syntax. It must be `["xxx" => ($balance - 123)]` or `["xxx" => ($balance + 123)]`.

You are confusing with a variable:

```php
$variable -= 123;
$variable += 123;
```

The use of `[ ]` is for arrays, is same as `array()`:

```php
$array1 = [
    "index1" => 123
];

echo $array1["index1"];
```

That would print `123`...

---

Edit:

To your new update, you are trying to use `$bal` as a number value, but that is a `Builder` as the error states, you must do `->first()` so you get the `Model` and then you can do `$bal->balance`.

So, do this:

```php
// Getting balance field in pivot table based on user_id & wallet_id
$bal = Wallet::with("users")->whereHas('users', function ($query) use ($wallet_id,$user_id) {
    $query->where('wallet_id',$wallet_id);
    $query->where('user_id',$user_id);
})->first();

// updating balance field    
$wallet = Wallet::find($wallet_id);
if($value_added_type == '-'){
    $wallet->users()->updateExistingPivot($user_id, ["balance" => ($bal->balance - $amount_add_value)]);
}else{
    $wallet->users()->updateExistingPivot($user_id, ["balance" => ($bal->balance + $amount_add_value)]);
}
```

Or use the corresponding field related to `balance`. I used `->balance` but I have no idea what your Model/Database is.

Comment: I tried this and added an **UPDATE #1** to the question. I get `Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to number` error!

Comment: @cerealikaeme see the update I have made in my answer